# Error on a Sort function error while trying to sort a file of structs A-Z

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, struct, swap

I have been trying to get this sort code working almost all Night, Anyways I am getting on last error on this line of code:

```
if(A[c]>A[c+1]) swap(A,c,c+1);
```

It is giving me an error on the `>` saying no operator matches these operands. I have seen this error before if I messed up a `>>` or `<<` while inputting or outputting, But this is a completely different problem.

Entire Code:

```
   #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm> 
using namespace std;

struct salesTran {
string name;
double quantity,price;
};

bool compareByPrice(salesTran const &a, salesTran const &b)

    {
    return a.price < b.price;
}

void swap(salesTran A[], int i, int j);
void sort(salesTran A[], int size);

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, salesTran A)
{os << A.name << "\t" << A.quantity << "\t" << A.price;
return os;}
istream& operator >> (istream& is, salesTran& A)
{is >> A.name >> A.quantity >> A.price;
return is;}

int main()
{
   salesTran data[250];

ifstream fin;
fin.open("sales.txt");
ofstream fout;
fout.open("results.txt");

int index = 0;
fin >> data[index];
while(!fin.eof())
{
index++;
fin >> data[index];
}

sort(data, index);

for(int j=0; j < index; j++)
{ 
cout << data[j] << endl;
}

return 0;
}

void swap(salesTran A[], int i, int j)
{
salesTran temp;
temp =A[i];
A[j] = A[j];
A[j] = temp;
return;
}


bool compareByPrice(salesTran const &a, salesTran const &b)
{
    return a.price < b.price;


std::sort(data, data + index, compareByPrice);

return;
}
```

Comment: The error message says exactly what is wrong. There is no operator defined for comparing two salesTran objects.  (P.S. No need to write your own sort function. std::sort should work just fine once you define the comparison operator.)

Comment: @RaymondChen So after I define the operator I use std::sort? I will try to look up std:sort I'm not sure what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overloading `operator>` on `salesTran` would be a bad idea because each field of `salesTran` is a perfectly valid way to compare two transactions.  People reading your code (or API!) would have to look at the documentation to find out which one is used.

Instead, you can define a comparison function and use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

```
#include <algorithm>

bool compareByPrice(salesTran const &a, salesTran const &b)
{
    return a.price < b.price;
}

std::sort(data, data + index, compareByPrice);
```

A C++11 lambda function would work too if you're into that.

Comment: so when I add the above code it says std has no member of sort. Can you point me in the right direction to fix this? I have never used std:sort before

Comment: Thank you for helping me in teaching me something entirely new and more effecient! I added that but now it is saying data and index are undefined which is weird because. They are defined. aren't they?

Comment: They're defined at the point you call `sort` in your original code.  So put the function definition at the beginning of the file and the `std::sort` call exactly where you called `sort` originally.

Comment: dumb question. I'm sorry. This is my 2nd week in c++ and coding in general. bool compareByPrice(salesTran const &a, salesTran const &b). This is the function definition correct? Because I put it up at the top and it did not fix the error. I'm sure I just did something wrong

Comment: That, plus the whole part afterward with curly braces.  No problem, C++ is really tough for a first language!

Comment: I added it ,But I am getting the same error. This is what my whole code looks like. I'll edit it in the original post

Comment: Okay, I updated my OP with my current code. If you code please just help me with this last error on finding out why data and index are not defined I would be very appreciative

Comment: everything's good up to the line where you call `sort()`.  Remove that and replace it with the call to `std::sort`.  Get rid of all the other changes you made after that.

Comment: I edited that line and put in std:: sort but then it said std was undefined in that line. Will it let you just edit the OP? I think I am misunderstanding you.

Comment: Thank you. So much. Just Thank You. I've learned so much more then I even needed to for the assignment!

Comment: When I run the code, the console menu is blank. Why on Earth is that? The code runs with no errors. Why is the console blank?

Comment: Try using a debugger or writing some status messages to `cout` to understand what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely is originating in the types of the data that you are trying to compare, for example, comparing two integers with the `>` relational operator will work, because it supports that type of comparison. However, you cannot compare two arrays in that way, because the built-in relational operators were not made to compare whole arrays. The only way you can get away with doing something like that is by overloading the operator itself.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/

Comment: I believe I need to add in another definition to allow for lexicographical swapping. Something that tells the program that A>B or something along that nature. Is this the right direction?

Comment: @user2133925, something like that... I updated my link to give you more information on that. If you look at the example on the link it will tell you about overloading, but you just have to apply this to `>` and `<`

Comment: @easzer001 okay well I'm pretty clueless because I have never attempted this before, but I'll give it a shot. Thanks for your help. If you have any other suggestions, feel free

Comment: @user2133925, no problem, it's good to learn but, japreiss posted an answer above that is completely valid as well. As a matter of fact, it's a better solution. I just answered your question directly.

Comment: thank you for helping me learn something new. I am trying to figure it out, but it is saying data and index are Thank you for helping me in teaching me something entirely new and more effecient! I added that but now it is saying data and index are undefined which is weird because. They are defined. aren't they?. Also how do I link code in a comment. I tried ctrl-k and that's not working... Sorry noobie here =/

Comment: @user2133925: click on the help link to the right of the comment box. It will show you how.